# Are SSIS Package Template Useful in 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have used SSIS Package Templates in 2005 and 2008 to enforce some standards and provide for some reuse in my packages.  But with the improvements in 2012 (Project Deployment Model, Connection Managers, Parameters, and Configurations) is there really much use for a package template any longer?

Answer (score 0):

your question doesn't make much sense to be honest.
If you are planning on migrating to SQL 2012, your templates wont be usefull unless you migrate them too.

If you want to know HOW usefull is a template in 2012, thats a different question. I cant really anser this because I did not have that much exposure to 2012, what I can say is that, in my opinion, for most of the reasons why you would create a template on 2005 and 2008 (the ones you listed on your question) you wouldnt need to create for 2012.

Comment: >>If you want to know HOW usefull is a template in 2012<< Well, that was exactly the question to be honest.  Having used 2012 for a while now, I still can't see a pressing reason for package templates, unless you just don't like the out of the box features (or they just don't do what you need).